# Print the file according to the pattern

Tags: unix

Consider a file "test" containing following data:

```
REG NO: 123
20
24
REG NO: 124
30
70
```

Need to print the following:

```
123 20
123 24
124 30
124 70
```

The value need to be printed from different fields. And content of the heding column (regno ie 123,124) need to repeated for their marks.

Comment: `echo '123 20 123 24 124 30 124 70'`

Comment: @user8287221 - Format your question properly. Also show if you have tried anything so far

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NF>1 {p=$NF;next} {print p, $1}' file
123 20
123 24
124 30
124 70
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NF>1 {            # when a record has more than one field
    p=$NF         # store the last field to p var
    next          # proceed to next record
} 
{
    print p, $1   # otherwise output the p and the value on the record
}' file
```

Comment: Consider a file "test" containing following data:
REG NO: 123
20
24
REG NO: 124
30
70

Need to print the following:
123 20
123 24
124 30
124 70
The value need to be printed from different fields. And content of the heding column (regno ie 123,124) need to repeated for their marks.

Comment: So it's the first part of my answer then. If not, please edit the question and especially the data. Tip: use the `{}` in editor (or prefix data with 4 spaces)